# Add static vertically and horizontally centred caption (or other content) to Bootstrap 4's Carousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

In addition to the standard captions used by Bootstrap 4's carousel element, I'd like to overlay a static caption (or other content) in a responsive way over a full-screen carousel. I've found solutions (such as this one) for this which involve absolutely positioning a div and specifying a value for the `top` (eg 30%), however this only really works when you know the height of the static caption in advance.

I've been able to partially achieve this as below...

html:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        ...
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="h-100 w-100 static-caption">
            <div class="d-flex text-center h-100">
                <div class="my-auto w-100 ">
                    <h1>Static caption here</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
                <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 350px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.static-caption {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

However, this feels a bit hacky (especially with `z-index:1`) and completely covers the carousel, making it impossible to click the controls (hence the `pointer-events:none`). Also it's 100% of the width, so the text overlaps the left/right controls. Reducing the width keeps the overlay left aligned and not centred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following code where your caption's class is `carousel-caption`

```
.carousel-caption {
  width: 50%; height: 50%; left:25%; top:25%
}
```

**issue is resolved by the code snippet above.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that vertical alignment isn't the issue - the problem is that making the caption less than 100% width and keeping it horizontally centred.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that vertical alignment isn't the issue - the problem is that making the caption less than 100% width and keeping it horizontally centred.

Comment: try left: 50% and margin-left: -0.5rem then

Comment: Thank you! Went with `width: 50%; height: 50%; left:25%; top:25%`

Comment: Thank you! Went with `width: 50%; height: 50%; left:25%; top:25%`

Comment: If you solved the issue, please mark answer as correct answer please for future reasearchers of the same issue.